# What are the methods available in storing sequential files?

Tags: file, data-structures, sequential

I have certain doubts about how the sequential files are stored and I would like to know about it.

Comment: That question isn't much to go on. Sequential files of what? What languages are you talking about?

Comment: This question seems very general, would you be able to provide some more details regarding your situation?

Answer (score 2):

The way in which sequential files are stored is mostly irrelevant, what does matter is that sequential files can be accessed sequentially from your program. This is in contrast to random access files which can be accessed by using a 'record index' to go to a specific record in the file.

However, in today's systems and programming languages there's little actual difference between the two modes, since you can 'seek' to any position within a sequential file in a very efficient manner. In fact, the concept of random access files and sequential files stopped being used many years ago.

Answer (score 1):

The methods available in storing sequential files are:

- Straight merging
- Natural merging
- Polyphase sort
- Distribution of Initial runs

Comment: still, a bit of explanation of the answer would be more useful

Comment: I'm tempted to flag *Not an Answer*: The bullets name procedures used in ("external") *sorting* (sequential) files, while the question is `about how the sequential files are` *`stored`*.